# How to remove DataGrid's blank row when binding to a ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: datagrid, observablecollection, wpftoolkit

I'm getting nuts here with this:

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> list = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
dgEmployees.ItemsSource = list;
```

When you debug the list variable, it's empty (list.Count =0), but then I bind it to a DataGrid (WPFToolkit), it shows me a blank row.

In immediate window, for dgEmployees.Items it's showing:

```
dgEmployees.Items[0]
{NewItemPlaceholder}
```

and

```
dgEmployees.Items[0].GetType()
{Name = "NamedObject" FullName = "MS.Internal.NamedObject"}
[System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "NamedObject" FullName = "MS.Internal.NamedObject"}
```

It seems to happen after I've put this Datagrid into a TabControl, but I'm not sure it has something to do with it.

Does anyone know how to remove this blank row?

Comment: You should accept the other answer, it's better than yours

Comment: I got the exception `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type MyClass` in external code through one of my bindings. Found out this extra empty line was the culprit! But the answer of Pablonete was better for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've got it

on Datagrid XAML, put the attribute:

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```

Comment: This is not correct answer. This is correct - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064128/987850

Answer (score 99):

The same problem persist in WPF 4.0 version of DataGrid, and it is caused by the add-new row which it shows automatically for ObservableCollection ItemsSource. Setting IsReadOnly as True it's too radical IMHO.
I solved it by disabling CanUserAddRows property if you don't need that behavior, but you still want cells to be modified:

> CanUserAddRows="False"

Comment: agreed unless it is truly readonly then that seems over kill.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me a lot more than the IsReadOnly which in my case had some side effects that I didn't want.

Comment: Can we mark this as the answer as IsReadOnly does have side-effects while this does not?

Answer (score 5):

`CanUserAddRows="False"` and `IsReadOnly="True"` combination of both is better to ensure any additional inconveniences.

Comment: you are suggesting he use two overlapping functionalities where either one will suffice and in fact `IsReadOnly = true` will remove other functionality with no gain at all.