# Binding Itemscontrol to ObservableCollection: extra generated item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

Binding `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` places an extra `{NewItemPlaceholder}` in the control at runtime. How can I remove it?

**N.B.** I have seen [posts related to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337258/how-to-remove-datagrids-blank-row-when-binding-to-a-observablecollectiont) but those are limited to `DataGrid` where you can set `CanUserAddRows` or `IsReadOnly` properties to get rid of this item. `ItemsControl` doesn't have any such property.

**XAML**

Here's my `ItemsControl` (`MyPoints` is `ObservableCollection<T>` in the underlying ViewModel):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyPoints}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PointVM}">
      <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="#88FF2222" />
    </DataTemplate>       
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This displays an extra point at 0,0. Live Property Explorer shows that this point is bound to the `{NewItemPlaceholder}` object.

Comment: Actually it works fine for me when adding points from ViewModel this way:  
    `MyPoints = new ObservableCollection<MyPoint>
    {
         new MyPoint { X = 2, Y = 3},
         new MyPoint { X = 40, Y = 60}
    };`   
Is your ObservableCollection binded to somewhere else as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN writes the following:

> When a `CollectionView` that implements `IEditableCollectionView` has
>   `NewItemPlaceholderPosition` set to `AtBeginning` or `AtEnd`, the
>   `NewItemPlaceholder` is added to the collection. The `NewItemPlaceholder`
>   always appears in the collection; it does not participate in grouping,
>   sorting, or filtering.

Link: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.newitemplaceholder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hopefully if you set the `NewItemPlaceholderPosition` to something else, the placeholder will disappear from the collection.

**Edit:**

If your `ObservableCollection<T>` is being binded to somewhere else as well (e.g.: to a `DataGrid`, you have to set the `CanUserAddRows` to false), you have to deal with that other item. It would add a new `NewItemPlaceholder` to your collection.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't appear to implement `IEditableCollectionView`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you add the xaml part of the `ItemsControl`'s settings to your question, please?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I changed `ObservableCollection<T>` to `List<T>` and could still see the extra item. I went as far as actually removing the dependency property to which `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` was binding and instead used direct binding with the VM property, but can still see the unwanted item in the `ItemsControl`. Pretty much done here. :(

Comment: Try to create a new project, and add only the `ObservableCollection<T>` and the `ItemsControl`. That must work. Then try to build up other xaml elements which are using the collection.

Comment: Your guess was correct. My `ObservableCollection<T>` was bound to a `DataGrid` too, which was actually responsible for the extra item. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, I'm glad we've solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Finally finally!

After spending a day, the solution turned out to be simple (although not ideal). `ItemTemplateSelector` allows me to select a template based on the item type, so I can create a simple selector to get rid of the extra item:

```
public class PointItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    if (item == CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder)
      return (container as FrameworkElement).TryFindResource("EmptyDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
    else
      return (container as FrameworkElement).TryFindResource("MyDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
  }
}
```

`MyDataTemplate` and `EmptyDataTemplate` should be defined in the `Resources` section of your `ItemsControl`. `EmptyDataTemplate` doesn't need to have any content.

### Edit

@KAI's guess (see accepted answer) was correct. My `ObservableCollection<T>` was bound to a `DataGrid` which was causing this problem. I'll still keep my answer here as it provides a solution for other related situations.