# Binding several ItemsControl to one ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf

I have two tabs.

The code of both tabs is in the same XAML file (yes, it must be)

Each tab references the same ObservableCollection

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectorItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Depending on the tab, the collection is reloaded and contains other data

The problem is that it only displays in the last tab.

I know that this results from logical parents but I am looking for a solution in this situation

If I had a bookmark code in a separate XAML it would not be a problem but I can not use it

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201128/binding-itemscontrol-to-observablecollection-extra-generated-item) may help you

Comment: ConnectorItems should not be a collection of UI elements. It should instead be a collection of data items, and the ItemsControl's ItemTemplate should be a DataTemplate with UI elements that bind to the properties of an individual data item.

Comment: @Clemens In simple cases, this should be the case. But here I have a very complicated situation. There are different possibilities, many conditions on which a different appearance of the element depends

Comment: All that is usually done by different DataTemplates for different data item types. Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).